# mysql query on php doesn't work

Tags: php, html

code:

```
<?php
include "init.php";
include_once('tbs_class.php');
$TBS = new clsTinyButStrong;
$TBS->LoadTemplate('/home/b2bmomo/www/templates/templateb2bmomo.htm');
$TBS->Show();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables";
        $risultati=$db->mysqli_query($query);
        while ( $row = $risultati->fetch_row() ){
            $table = $row[0];
            echo '<h3>'.$table.'</h3>';
        }
}
?>
```

This is the query of my index should print me all the tables in my db which I connect in init.php that comes included , the part is loaded into a html template tiny butstrong , this is the structure of html

code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>B2BMOMO</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/include/css/bootflat.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/include/css/app.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/s/bs/pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.10,af-2.1.0,b-1.1.0,b-colvis-1.1.0,b-html5-1.1.0,b-print-1.1.0,cr-1.3.0,fc-3.2.0,fh-3.1.0,kt-2.1.0,r-2.0.0,rr-1.1.0,sc-1.4.0,se-1.1.0/datatables.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div align="center">ELENCA TABELLE PRESENTI NEL DB</div>
        <form method="post" action="index.php" style="text-align: center;">
            <INPUT type="submit" value="Invia">
            <br><br>
        </form>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="/include/js/bootstrap-contextmenu.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/include/js/bootflat.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/s/bs/pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.10,af-2.1.0,b-1.1.0,b-colvis-1.1.0,b-html5-1.1.0,b-print-1.1.0,cr-1.3.0,fc-3.2.0,fh-3.1.0,kt-2.1.0,r-2.0.0,rr-1.1.0,sc-1.4.0,se-1.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now , I wish that clicking the button in the index is given me to output the list of tables in the db , but at present the query was

code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables";
        $risultati=$db->mysqli_query($query);
        while ( $row = $risultati->fetch_row() ){
            $table = $row[0];
            echo '<h3>'.$table.'</h3>';
        }
}
```

I will not print anything, does anyone have any idea ? thank you

Comment: is your query actually pulling results from the database?

Comment: Try making it throw errors, then debug from there

Comment: no at this moment when i press button submit nothing it happens

Answer (score 0):

First of all, unless you're using a custom class, I think that you confuse procedural and objected oriented style.

This doesn't work:

```
$db->mysqli_query( $query );
```

This works:

```
$db->query( $query );
```

In addition, `SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables` doesn't show all the tables in our database. It display instead all the rows in table `TABLES` from database `information_schema` (it's not the same: see more about [information_schema tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html)).

To display a list of all tables from your current database, use this query:

```
"SHOW TABLES"
```